# m4_include does not expand its argument?

Tags: autoconf, m4

Assume a trivial `configure.ac`:

```
AC_INIT([foobar], 1.0)
m4_define([foobar_m4], [foobar.m4])
m4_include(foobar_m4)
```

with a trivial `foobar.m4`:

```
AS_ECHO(["foobar.m4 was included"])
```

Running `autoreconf` produces:

```
aclocal: error: configure.ac:10: file 'foobar_m4' does not exist
autoreconf-2.69: aclocal failed with exit status: 1
```

How to include m4-expanded filenames in a `configure.ac`?

Answer (score 3):

The culprit is the `aclocal` utility, not `m4`. The `m4` expansion works just fine, but before `m4` is invoked, `aclocal` scans `configure.ac` for dependencies, and it blindly handles the `m4_include` macro as if it were always called with a literal file argument.

There are two workarounds:

1. Use the built-in macro `include`:

   ```
   m4_builtin([include], foobar_m4)
   ```

This will completely circumvent the autoconf-provided `m4_include` macro, which protects against repeated inclusions of the same file.

2. Define your own macro that invokes `m4_include`:

   ```
   m4_define([my_include], [m4_include][([$1])])dnl
   my_include(foobar_m4)
   ```

Why the weird quoting? We have to quote `m4_include` in the above definition so that it is not expanded during the definition of `my_include`, but quoting the whole `m4_include([$1])` invocation would still trip `aclocal` in the same way as in the question.

As far as I know, there is no built-in way to prevent `aclocal` from specially treating the `m4_include` macro. This behavior of `aclocal` is essential for dependency tracking, so including files in this way is likely to fail due to undefined macros used in included files (this is also explained [here](http://thread.gmane.org/gmane.comp.sysutils.autoconf.general/13724/focus=13728)).